# What is the alternative of PK analyzer in Hybris?

Tags: primary-key, hsqldb, sap-commerce-cloud

PK analyzer in Hybris HAC is blocked for a reason. Is there another way by which I can determine to which item this PK belongs to ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to use HMC:

_your_server_/hmc/hybris?open=_YOUR_PK_

Comment: Now in backoffice with /backoffice/#open(_YOUR_PK_) see https://help.sap.com/viewer/9b5366ff6eb34df5be29881ff55f97d2/v1811/en-US/7439bda571794d8c94768df86d739519.html

Answer (score 2):

The PK has a specific structure. Encoded in the PK is the typecode. Using the typecode you can specify the itemtype. With the itemtype you can search in the right place in your backoffice/hmc.

The typecode consists of the last 15 digits in the binary representation of the PK.

PK: 8798395039745

Binary: 10000000000010001001001101100000000000000001

Last 15 Digits: 000000000000001

Typecode: 1

Now search for the type with typecode 1 -> Product. Finally search for a product with the PK.

See structure here: 
https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/8c2d4abd866910149207b2f33deaf652.html
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Primary+Keys

Comment: Nice piece of advice mate ! I'll pick a note. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to run FlexibleSearchQuery, you can still identify PK

Try this

```
select {composedType.code} from {Item as item}, {ComposedType as composedType} where {item.itemtype}={composedType.pk} and {item.pk}=?PK
```

replace `?pk` with the value which you want to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

Get Model with PK using Groovy Script

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.PK;
def a=spring.getBean("modelService")
println a.get(PK.parse("8796093057016"))
```

Comment: I need to make some amends to the script. But thats a nice idea too.